# Android: How to filter an object?

Tags: android, android-listview, filter, android-adapter, android-filter

I have displayed 10 different values in a list by using adapter. Each list have 10 different values. If i have only one object which holds different value in a list then i can directly use ArrayAdapter to filter it. But in my case, I'am using different objects to display the values. Now i want to filter the list based on the single value. How can i achieve this scenario?

Here is my full code.

```
public class CustomEventAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
List<CalEvent> cont;
private CalEvent con;
private EventType event;
private EventStates states;
public static List<Meeting> mlist;
Context ctx;
TextView textView,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5,textView6,textView7,actualend,meeting_place,meeting_person;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
public static Meeting meet;
static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
static AlarmManager alarmManager;
Button start_end_meet;
public CustomEventAdapter(Context ctx, List<CalEvent> cont) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.cont = cont;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return cont.size();
}

@Override
public CalEvent getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return cont.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return cont.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pd_eve_list_detail, parent,false);
    textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.start_Date);
    textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.actual_start);
    textView3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.requirement);
    textView4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pd_event_type);
    textView5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_state);
    textView6 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.current_stage);
    textView7 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.notes);
    meeting_place = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.meeting_place);
    meeting_person = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.meet_person);
    con = getItem(position);
    event = EventType.getEventType(con.event_type);
    states = EventStates.getEventStates(con.event_state);
    try {
        textView5.setText(states.name);
        textView.setText(con.event_start);
        textView2.setText(con.actual_start);
        textView4.setText(event.name);
        textView7.setText(con.notes);
        meeting_place.setText(con.followup_location);
        meeting_person.setText(con.person_met);
        System.out.println(event.name+states.name+con.followup_location);
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

Please do help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: implement Filterable interface in your CustomEventAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this component:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidFilterableList

This component allows you filtering dinamically, filter by a property of an object etc.

You only have to implement two interfaces with its method... no more. See the instructions for it.

You can also find a sample, which will make the implementation easier for you.

Give it a chance!! I hope this would help you ;)

Comment: No it is not. You have to import it as an ordinary android library project from properties/android etc.

Comment: I have extracted your zip file and i got LauncherMainActivity. I have imported in my workspace and i tried to add the library. But i can't see your library file.

Comment: I can't see your library file when i give add library.

Comment: Mark my project as library (property/android etc.) and try again importing...it should appear there.;)